# Bootstrap horizontal dropdown menu aligned to right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had problem with aligning my horizontal drop down menu to right side of `row` container. It is because I have `position:fixed` in my css but it is only way to style this type of menu.

Here is my css:

```
.top-main .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 87px;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And whole menu you can see here: http://www.bootply.com/mNP0ficFef

As you can see the menu is aligned to right side of monitor, but it should be aligned to right side of `row`. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is "row" mean? are you talking about link1,link2 and link3

Comment: In bootstrap you have something like class="row" - it is "main" container who contains all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, all you have to do is set up a container within your dropdown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul class="list-inline container">
    <li><a href="#" id="">Link 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="">Link 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="">Link 1.3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="">Link 1.5</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/Pu3P6c2nlO

Answer (score 0):

Use inbuilt `pull-right` class on:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top pull-right" role="navigation">
   /* content */
</nav>
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/WCNHzzZpFe)